# How can I fix exception "Floating SnackBar presented off screen" in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, android-snackbar

I have an app that displays a snackbar when some action is done. I had tested this with my phone and some emulator and it works. Recently I installed an emulator with android 13 and maybe a bigger resolution and I'm getting this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Floating SnackBar presented off screen.

A SnackBar with behavior property set to SnackBarBehavior.floating is fully or partially off screen because some or all the widgets provided to Scaffold.floatingActionButton, Scaffold.persistentFooterButtons and Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar take up too much vertical space.

Consider constraining the size of these widgets to allow room for the SnackBar to be visible.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
dashboard.dart:69
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout.<anonymous closure>
#0      _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout.<anonymous closure>
scaffold.dart:1189
#1      _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
scaffold.dart:1204
#2      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
custom_layout.dart:240
#3      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
custom_layout.dart:410
#4      RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
object.dart:2027
#5      PipelineOwner.flushLayout
object.dart:1020
#6      RendererBinding.drawFrame
binding.dart:516
#7      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
binding.dart:865
#8      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
binding.dart:381
#9      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
binding.dart:1289
#10     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1218
#11     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1076
#12     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:13)
#13     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:338:5)
#14     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#3f6d8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#3f6d8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    needs compositing
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=867.4)
    size: Size(411.4, 867.4)
    child 1: RenderRepaintBoundary#ba78b relayoutBoundary=up1
        needs compositing
```

I have no idea how can I debug what is going on here. The code works in smaller devices/older versions of android. The popups are triggered quiet straightforward:

```dart
SnackBar getSnackbar({
  required String message,
  required Color backgroundColor,
}) {
  return SnackBar(
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    content: Row(children: [
      Flexible(
        child: Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
  );
}

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
 ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
 ..showSnackBar(getSnackbar(
 backgroundColor: Colors.green,
 message: 'File saved to $filename',
 ));
```

The screen where this is called does not have any Scaffold.floatingActionButton, Scaffold.persistentFooterButtons and Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar as the exception says. It is just a Scaffold with a body:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SomeScreen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: _isLoading
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Column(children: [
                _displaySomething(),
                Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    _displayAnotherThing(),
                  ],
                ))
              ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

*Update*: I have futher debugged the issue and it also happens in older versions of android. So it may be related to a recent update of flutter but I'm not able to find why.
I was able to see the problem appears only with `behavior:SnackBarBehavior.floating,`.

Also removing all the code from the Scaffolfd, leaving just the TextButton that triggers the snackbar is enough to reproduce the issue, but I don't know what can I do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120308), because I though it was a bug. But there it was explained that for the SnackBars you have to also consider other Scaffolds in the widget tree as moving backwards would keep the snackbar "flying" and could collide with elements of the previous Scaffolds.

So as a summary on how to solve this issue, take a look not only in the screen where you see the exception triggered but also from previous screens.

Comment: I confirm, I had an almost root previous page with two FloatingActionButtons, one above the other in a Column, making more vertical space. In my case removing one FAButton or adding mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min to the Column containing both buttons did the trick. The screen where I wanted to show the snackbar was 5 screens ahead.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `ScaffoldMessenger` widget was missing. After wrapping `Scaffold` with `ScaffoldMessenger`, it works for me.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          selectedPage: _bottomTabPosition,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This Works in Some Cases, But still not a proper solution as it does not always work.
Still Looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. This problem arises due to the fact that your column takes up all the available space, you need to limit it somehow to give room for a snackbar

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue. I have tested just a scaffold with a button in the body and I still get the exception.